# Is it possible to capture any unspecific input event in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I want my application to be able to display certain information when no user input has been detected for some time (like a Welcome/Instruction layer). Is there anyway to have the application register any form of user input (keyboard, mousedown/move etc) without having to write handlers for each of those events?

Is there a generic input window message that gets sent before it is interpreted as being mouse or keyboard or other device? The behaviour I want is similar to Windows waking up from screen saver / sleep on keyboard or mouse input.

I want to avoid something like:

```
void SomeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) { WakeUp(); }
...
this.KeyDown += SomeHandler;
this.MouseMove += SomeHandler;
this.SomeInputInteraction += SomeHandler;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetLastInputInfo Function](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial210_Retrieving-the-Operating-System-Idle-Time-Uptime-and-Last-Input-Time.html) is probably what you're looking for.  It retrieves the time of the last input event.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in WPF but this may help:

```
public class DetectInput : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {

        if (   m.Msg == (int)WindowsMessages.WM_KEYDOWN 
            || m.Msg == (int)WindowsMessages.WM_MOUSEDOWN  
            // add more input types if you want
            )
        {
            // Do your stuff here
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and in Program:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new DetectInput ()); // Must come before Run
Application.Run(YourForm);
```